# Error on trying to jsonDecode String in Flutter application

Tags: json, flutter, dart

When I try to decode a json String: `[{"device-mac":"C9BF2EB47C17","on":true}]` with the following function the error:

> I/flutter ( 8954): type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'String'

get's thrown.

My function is this one, the json String is loaded from a Rest API endpoint:

```
Future<void> _getDevices() async {
    var parsedList;
    try {
      final response = await restApiClient.get(
        '/getDevices',
      );
      List<dynamic> parsedListJson = jsonDecode(response.data);
      List<Device> itemsList =
          List<Device>.from(parsedListJson.map((i) => Device.fromJson(i))); 
    
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure response.data is [{"device-mac":"C9BF2EB47C17","on":true}]? Please share Device implementation.

Comment: `response.data` probably is `[{"device-mac":"C9BF2EB47C17","on":true}]`  (i.e., it's already been decoded) and not the string `'[{"device-mac":"C9BF2EB47C17","on":true}]'`. `jsonDecode` expects a `String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the reason for it not working was that my REST endpoint already returned a list JSON Type which made the function "jsonDecode" redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can parse Sting only and you passed a List of maps, you should either make a loop and then cast the map to string using 'response.data.toString' and then add the value to the list or if it's always one value try using 'response.data.first.toString()

Answer (score 0):

I think it can parse Sting only and if you passed a List of maps, you should either make a loop and then cast the map to string using 'response.data.torturing and then add the value to the list or if it's always one value try using 'response.data.first.toString()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).